# Calculating time complexity of a tree which splits in 1:3 ratio unlike binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity

How do we calculate the time complexity of a tree which splits in an uneven manner say in the ratio of 1:3 unlike the typical binary tree splitting in two equal halves?

Comment: Did you have a particular algorithm in mind?

Answer (score 1):

This smells of homework, but I'll give it a go anyway.

A tree doesn't inherently have time complexity, but I think I get what you mean.

Most algorithms with a nicely balanced tree have a log2(n) component to their complexity. If you split it in thirds instead, the base of the logarithm will be 3/2.

So where a binary search in a regular binary search tree would be in O(log2(n)), in your scenario, it would be O(log3/2(n)).

That said, the base of a logarithm can be changed by multiplying a constant, and we don't take constants into account in complexity theory. So technically, while the worst case is slower in this scenario, it's in the same time complexity.